# Is there a way I can compile with bash instead of cmd?

Tags: python, linux, windows, bash

I'm running Windows 10 and I'm watching someone that running Linux.

He is teaching the `subprocess` module and shows how to call commands through the terminal (in Linux).

My problem is that Linux's commands are different than the commands in Windows, for example for `ifconfig` you need to call `ipconfig /all` in Windows.

So I went to the Microsoft Store and downloaded a product called Kali Linux.

My question is how can I use bash instead of cmd in Visual Studio?

**Example:**

```
import subprocess

# Linux command
subprocess.call('ifconfig', shell=True)

# Windows command
subprocess.call('ipconfig /all', shell=True)
```

The Python terminal or cmd can't recognize `ifconfig` command.

Comment: Have you considered [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)?

Comment: @PM77-1 Hey, This is not what I'm looking for. I want to compile my Python programs with bash instead of cmd. So the `ifconfig` command will execute properly and the bash will recognize it.

Comment: easiest way: first install windows package manager `Chocolatey` (https://chocolatey.org/install) and then install cygwin (https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin)

Comment: @PM77-1 and Lonely: Has Cygwin any advantage compared to WSL? I don't understand why Cygwin is still recommended so often when there is WSL directly built into Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). With WSL you can execute bash from within Windows' `cmd`. You just have to pass the commands you want to execute in bash to the `bash` command using its `-c` option:

```
subprocess.call('bash -c ifconfig', shell=True)
```

Please note that the whole command has to be passed as a single argument to `bash`. That is, if you want to execute `ls -l` you have to use `bash -c "ls -l"`.

If you want to execute multiple commands with multiple `subprocess.call` then you have to use `bash -c` in every call or change the default shell (see [python's manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)):

> On Windows with `shell=True`, the `COMSPEC` environment variable specifies the default shell.

The `cmd` command `where bash` reveals the path you have to specify in `COMPSPEC` to change the default shell to `bash`. On my Windows 10 system it is `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`.